# Highcharts - Redraw/Resize chart after destroying legend?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am building several charts on the fly on some of them I remove the legend using chart.legend.destroy(). I have tried chart.reflow() and chart.redraw but the charts do not "refit" themselves and stay the same size as if the legend was still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little convoluted.

You can destroy the legend but Highcharts doesn't recognize that it needs to re-adjust for a missing legend.  So, you need to set it's display to `false`.  But now Highcharts doesn't realize it's `dirty` so it won't redraw.  So...

```
    var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    chart.legend.destroy();
    chart.legend.display = false;
    chart.isDirtyBox = true;
    chart.redraw();
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/psvebL74/).

Answer (score 0):

You can call setSize like in the example:

```
if(legend.display) {
            chart.setSize(600,400);
            legend.group.hide();
            legend.display = false;
        } else {
            chart.setSize(500,400);
            legend.group.show();
            legend.display = true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh7b/61/